# Question about Bounded Operators

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert Space. Suppose $B$ is a linear map with the property that if $u_n \to u$ and $B(u_n) \to v$, then $v=B(u)$. Show that $B$ is bounded.

So the issue here is to get some sequence that $B$ will be continuous on and then proceed by some sort of scaling, but I don't see how to find such a sequence...perhaps involving the basis?

Any tips helpful.

Comment: Are you familiar with the elementary result that a linear  $f:C\to D$  between Banach spaces $C,D$ is continuous iff $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ iff $ f$ is bounded ?

Answer (score 7):

Use the closed graph theorem. If $(u_n, B(u_n)) $ converges towards $(u, v) $, $u_n$ converges towards $u$ and the hypothesis implies that $v=B(u) $ so the graph is closed.